# I could not point correctly the static image files

Tags: python, html, django, web

**index.html**

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            {% for pizza in pizza_list %}
                {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} 
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img width="250" height="850" class="d-block w-100 h-50" class="h-50 d-inline-block" src="{% static 'Pizza/{{ pizza }}' %}" alt="...">
                        
                    </div>    
                {% else %}
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img width="250" height="850" class="d-block w-100 h-50" class="h-50 d-inline-block" src="{% static 'Pizza/{{ pizza }}' %}" alt="...">
                      
                    </div>
                {% endif %} 

            {% endfor %}
        
        </div>
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    pizza_list = []
    print(os.getcwd())
    for item in os.listdir('static/Pizza'):

        pizza_list.append(item)
 ## print(pizza_list)
    
    context = {'pizza_list':pizza_list}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py** under `Main_Project` folder

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('pizza.urls')),
   
]

urlpatterns += static(
    settings.STATIC_URL,
    document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My project directory

```
Main_Project (top)
--Main_Project (top)
  --settings
  --urls
--pizza 
  --static
    --Pizza
      --(images)
   --templates
   --migrations
   --views.py
   --models.py
   --urls.py
```

In this Django project, I have a confusion about where should the static images and files put under because I could not load the image in `index.html` that I saved in the static folder directory. Also, I am not sure whether my settings are correct in order to have the images shown on the templates but when I tried to print `pizza_list` it could show the image file names. May I ask what is the best folder structure in order to have the templates recognize the image files in static folder to display?

Comment: Try to input the {{ pizza }} tag in your html to see whether it actually renders the pats of a sing Pizza object. I would recommend using the ListView CBV for this case

Comment: first you should see HTML in browser to see what urls you created in this HTML. `os.listdir(folder)` gives only filenames and you may need to add `folder` to filenames to create full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Did you {% load static %}?
2. I assume the {{ pizza }} variable is an image. If so then use this:

```
<img src="{% static 'Pizza/{{ pizza.url }}' %}" />
```